# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{2}{k^{p}x^{k} \over 1 + x^{2k}}\,{\rm d}x\quad\mbox{with}\quad k = 1,2,3,\ldots\quad\mbox{and constant}\quad p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider the integrals
$$
\int_{0}^{2}{k^{p}x^{k} \over 1 + x^{2k}}\,{\rm d}x\quad\mbox{with}\quad
k = 1,2,3,\ldots\quad\mbox{and constant}\quad p.
$$
For what values of $p$ do the integrands have an integrable majorant ?. For what $p$ do the integrals tend to $0$ ?.

It seems like I can just pull the $k^{p}$, so I tried doing that and simply evaluating the integral but things just aren't seeming to work out that way.

Answer (score 2):

The integral from $0$ to $1$ is within a factor of $2$ of $\int_0^1 x^k k^p dx = k^p/(k+1),$ which shows that the integrals do not converge for $p>1,$ and do not converge to $0$ for $p=1.$ The integral from $1$ to $2$ is smaller than $\int_1^2k^p x^{-k} dx = (1-2^{-k+1}) k^p/(k+1),$ which goes to zero if $p<1.$